# How to change position of node queue list in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, nodequeue

I already create a nodequeue with 3 queue list.

**Screen**
[image]

I want to change the order of queue list like as

```
Sample 2
Sample 1
Sample 3
```

Any hook functions available for change the nodequeue positions?

Thanks for advise!

Comment: maybe this can help https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2017-06-29/how-to-sort-views-based-on-node-queue-list

Comment: @Fky. No. I want to change the "gueues name" position. Here is no drag and drop. Any idea?

Comment: Check if module provide .api file with hooks to override sort , otherwise you have to develop your own